# Invalidating tile cache

Tags: android, tiles, osmdroid, openstreetmap

I am making an app that uses osmdroid.

The map data on the server that the app connects to may change at any time so I would like to be able to invalidate the tile cache for osmdroid so that it re-renders the mapview with the correct data.

Is there any way to do this? Ideally for just a specific region of the map.

Thanks